# Subsetting data with a vec

Tags: r, subset

I want to subset a data frame by a vector, but replicate the subsetting for each value in the vector:

```
data = data.frame(A = c(1,2,3,1), B = c(1,2,3,4))
vec = c(1, 1, 1)
subset(data, A %in% vec)
  A B
1 1 1
4 1 4
```

Instead of this result I want this:

```
  A B
1 1 1
4 1 4
1 1 1
4 1 4
1 1 1
4 1 4
```

Comment: Where does `B` come from? It's not in your data frame.

Answer (score 2):

If you use the `purrr` library, you can do

```
map_df(vec, function(x) subset(data, A == x))
```

with base R, it would be

```
do.call("rbind", lapply(vec, function(x) subset(data, A == x)))
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to expand it, i.e.

```
df2 <- subset(data, A %in% vec)
df2[rep(rownames(df2), length(vec)),]
#    A B
#1   1 1
#4   1 4
#1.1 1 1
#4.1 1 4
#1.2 1 1
#4.2 1 4
```

Answer (score 2):

One option with `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data, key = 'A')[.(vec)]
#   A B
#1: 1 1
#2: 1 4
#3: 1 1
#4: 1 4
#5: 1 1
#6: 1 4
```

Or use `merge`, which gives *cartesian product* as you need when there are duplicated values in the *merge-by* column:

```
merge(data, data.frame(A = vec))

#   A B
#1: 1 1
#2: 1 1
#3: 1 1
#4: 1 4
#5: 1 4
#6: 1 4
```

Answer (score 1):

Along the lines of a base R split-apply-combine solution would be

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(vec, function(i) data[data$A == i, ]))
   A B
1  1 1
4  1 4
11 1 1
41 1 4
12 1 1
42 1 4
```

This could be useful if vec contained an uneven mixture of values. This solution could be expensive if there are many repetitions in vec. In that instance, computation can be reduced by combining it with the `rep` idea in soto's answer as follows.

```
# count the number of repetitions by unique value
uni <- table(vec)
# extract unique values
temp <- lapply(as.numeric(names(uni)), function(i) data[data$A == i, ])
# combine results, repeating data.frames according to count
do.call(rbind, temp[rep(seq_along(uni), each=uni)])
```